# Android ormlite Multi-table mapping

Tags: android, ormlite, multi-table

I want to use ormlite in my android project, but I don't know how to solve the multi-table mapping.Some suggest?

Comment: What problem are you facing in  multi table mapping, are you confused as to how to generate the Config.txt file for the SEcond table ?

Comment: I haven't use Config.txt file, I use annotations to mark classes to be persisted.

Comment: Please provide more information.  This is an extremely short question with no background.  All we can do is guess at what you are talking about.

Comment: Well , I just don't know how to model a many-to-many relationship with ORMLite.

Answer (score 1):

ormlite provide ForeignKey concept . Using ForeignKey you can solve the problem of multiple table mapping .
Please see below link ([How to use Foreign](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign)).

Also see this link may be its help you
[ORMlite Android foreign key support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002519/ormlite-android-foreign-key-support)